# What is the need of 2 dvd images in centos 6.2?

Tags: centos, redhat, centos6

I have downloaded centos 6.2 via torrent.Then i got 2 dvd images.Then what is the use os second image.

How to use it?

Comment: have you tried actually looking at the contents of those images?

Answer (score 7):

What do you *think* it's for? do you think it might be full of images of kittens or might it just possibly have some, well, Centos code on it that you may need depending on installed options. This site is for pro-sysadmins (see FAQ), who tend to know the basics including how to think.

Comment: sometimes I think you got to 54k just by getting upvotes for these particular answers. Even if so - bloody good work :)

Comment: I didn't, to be fair when I wrote that I'd just discovered all the SWTOR servers were still down so expected to come back later and edit the answer but no, it still stands!

Comment: But we still love you Chopper3. :D